# Fixed Position DIV is cutoff when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-position, angular-material

I am working in Angular Material and I am running into an issue when I use `property: fixed`. The bottom portion of the div that is `fixed` gets cutoff when I scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page.

here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baiin/pp1ak0a7/

I've tried other solutions to fix this like using `scrollTop()` as an alternative to `position: fixed`, but it also produces the same bug. I think the solution is to check when I scroll if the bottom of the div is hitting the bottom of the page. However, I am unable to get a proper position for the div when it is being moved. I keep getting the same value. I need to find a way to get the position of this div relative to the entire page.

```
var offset = $("#scroll").offset();
console.log(offset.top); // doesn't give me relative position, just gives me constant value
```

Any input would help because I've been struggling with this problem for a while.

Comment: `// doesn't give me relative position, just gives me constant value` . it's because you have to include that calculation inside a scroll function. and then you will get a dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, may be it helps you

```
$(function() {
   var getTop = $('#scroll').offset().top; 
   log(getTop - $(window).scrollTop());

   $(window).scroll(function() { 
      console.log(getTop - $(window).scrollTop());
   });
});
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. $(window).scroll works on JSFiddle but not when I put it into my actual project folder. Is there a reason why this isn't triggering?

Comment: Did you add jquery library properly in your project folder?